# How to Get and Set a Property using Expression Trees in the Best Way?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

Instead of using Reflection, how can I set and get object properties using Expression Trees?

I have written the below class which works fine:

```
public class PropertyAccessor<TEntity>
    {
        private readonly PropertyInfo _memberInfo;
        private readonly TEntity _nom;

        public PropertyAccessor(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> fieldSelector, TEntity nom)
        {
            if (fieldSelector.Body is MemberExpression)
                _memberInfo = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)fieldSelector.Body).Member;

            else if (fieldSelector.Body is UnaryExpression)
                _memberInfo = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)fieldSelector.Body).Operand).Member;
            else
                throw new NotImplementedException("Field selector not supported");

            _nom = nom;
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get { return _memberInfo.GetValue(_nom, null); }
            set { _memberInfo.SetValue(_nom, value, null); }
        }
    }
```

and I use it like this:

```
Product product = ProductFactory.Build();
var propertyAccessor = new PropertyAccessor<Product>(p => p.Name, product);
var name = propertyAccessor.Value;
```

Is there any way to improve its performance further? Is the implementation the best way to do it?

Shouldn't I call the Compile() method on the expression before or after the constructor call?

What happens when a lambda expression is passed to an Expression of that lambda expression?

Is converting the MemberExpression to a PropertyInfo the best option? any performance penalties?

Comment: You're not using reflection? `PropertyInfo` belongs to reflection!

Comment: I thought so too, that's why I've asked the question what's the best way to implement this class using Expression.

Comment: May be you're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3475985/2530848)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a property is actually two separate methods, a get and a set. I also did not see any reason to use expressions here so I used delegates instead. If you must use an expression you can just compile it first.

```
public class PropertyAccessor<TEntity,TProperty>
{
    private readonly TEntity _nom;
    Func<TEntity, TProperty> _getter;
    Action<TEntity, TProperty> _setter;

    public PropertyAccessor(Func<TEntity, TProperty> getter, Action<TEntity, TProperty> setter, TEntity nom)
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;
        _nom = nom;
    }

    public object Value // the return type can be changed to TProperty
    {
        get { return _getter(_nom); }
        set { _setter(_nom, (TProperty)value); }
    }
}
```

This can be called like this:

```
var propertyAccessor = new PropertyAccessor<Product, String>(p => p.Name, (p, v) => p.Name = v, product);
```